# Looking for a "hurry up"

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Could the word: "пойдёмте" be used to tell someone to hurry up?
I get a lot of hits on a lot of other words on "hurry up".

Is "Скорее" a better word in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "hurry (sb/sth) up"

To translate the phrase into Russian, you will convert the `up` to prefix `по-`/`под-`, then insert that (sb/sth):

```
to ​move or do things more ​quickly than ​normal or to make someone do this:

по-спеши
по-торопись
по-торопливайся
по-шевеливайся
по-живее
по-скорее



  "We shan't get there till tomorrow going on like this. Hurry up!"
  The sledge-driver cranes his neck again, rises in his seat, 
  and with heavy grace swings his whip. 
                                        [Anton Chekhov. Misery]
  ― Этак мы и до завтра не доедем. Подгони-ка! Извозчик опять 
  вытягивает шею, приподнимается и с тяжелой грацией взмахивает кнутом.
```

If there is no (sb/sth), or not meant for inclusion that (sb/sth) from the context, then you used to insert words generally without `по-`

```
== скорее, скорей:
  Папа смеялся и кричал мне вслед: — Скорей, скорей, а то опоздаешь. 
                                                        [Leo Tolstoy. Childhood]
  Papa laughing as he shouted after me, "Hurry up, hurry up or you'll be late!"

  Hurry up! What news?
  Скорей, что нового?

== живо, живее:
  Now then, hurry up!
  Ну, живо!
```

Answer (score 1):

`Cкорее` is definitely better and more universal, but I can imagine a periodically repeated `пойдёмте` that is used as an incentive to move on.

Answer (score 1):

*Пойдёмте* and *Идёмте* are the same as *Let's go*. Sure, you may say "Let's go" instead of "Hurry up" under some circumstances, but technically these are not the same thing.

As a direct translation for "*Hurry up*" into Russian, I'd choose either *Быстрее* or *Поторапливайтесь* depending on whether you mean a stronger or weaker order.